# Firefox add-on: how to tell if a window is in the background

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

In a Firefox Add-on SDK add-on, how do I tell whether a window is in the background, ie. visible but not focused?

For example, if I bring a different application to the foreground, the Firefox window becomes unfocused but is still visible.

The reason why I want to do this is because I have a CPU-intensive content script running in the active window, and I'd like to pause it to avoid unnecessary overhead whenever the user isn't actively engaged with the window - meaning it's in the background or minimized.

`require("sdk/windows").activeWindow` keeps returning the last clicked window even if it's in the background or minimized. There doesn't seem to be any property for the window's focus state.

I can also get use the following code to get an nsIDocShell:

```
var mostRecentWindow = require("sdk/window/utils").getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
var docShell = require("sdk/window/utils").getWindowDocShell(mostRecentWindow);
```

Now when I query the `docShell.isActive` property, it returns true even if the window is in the background.

The one advantage of `docShell.isActive` is that it returns false when the window is minimized, while `activeWindow` returns true even in this case. But it's still missing information about whether the window is in the background or not.

Comment: Does the [`deactivate` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/windows#deactivate) work as you'd expect?

Comment: Huh, looks like it does. Previously I'd had trouble with both iframes and plugins, but it looks pretty robust now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestion by @willlma, this code seems to do the trick:

```
const windows = require('sdk/windows').browserWindows;
const tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var anyWindowActive = true;
var refreshTimeoutId;

windows.on('deactivate', function(window) {
    if (window == windows.activeWindow) {
        anyWindowActive = false;
    }
    clearTimeout(refreshTimeoutId);
    refreshTimeoutId = setTimeout(refreshTabStates, 50);
});

windows.on('activate', function(window) {
    anyWindowActive = true;
    clearTimeout(refreshTimeoutId);
    refreshTimeoutId = setTimeout(refreshTabStates, 50);
});

tabs.on('activate', function(tab) {
    clearTimeout(refreshTimeoutId);
    refreshTimeoutId = setTimeout(refreshTabStates, 50);
});

function refreshTabStates() {
    refreshTimeoutId = null;
    for (let win of windows) {
        for (let tab of win.tabs) {
            var shouldBeActive = anyWindowActive
                                 && tab == tabs.activeTab
                                 && win == windows.activeWindow;
            notifyTab(tab, shouldBeActive);
        }
    }
}
```

where `notifyTab()` is a function that posts a message to that tab's content script (if any) about whether it should be running or not.

`setTimeout` is used to avoid multiple calls to refreshTabStates in quick succession. For example, if you click on an inactive tab in a window that's not the current one, that one click results in `window.deactivate`, `window.activate` and `tab.activate` events.

Also, the initial state is a problem. What if the user launches Firefox and puts it in the background before any script has managed to run?

Comment: Can you test if the activate event is fired on startup? Then `anyWindowActive` should default to `false` and it would work as expected.

Comment: Sadly not. There are no window or tab events at startup, not activate or deactivate. I'm guessing the addon main.js runs just a bit too late to catch those events, if they're sent at all.